# Getting a gif to show up on a blob

Tags: javascript, html, css, blob

When users make selections for the first two inputs and click the download button, I want it to that them to a blob link that has the gif there. However, currently, when the users make selections and click the download button, it is properly taking them to a blob link but the gif is not showing up on it. The gif is trying to show up on the main link that the button is on and I am not sure how to fix it.

```js
document.getElementById('button_fg').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // show the box if it's hidden, or hide it if it's visible
  document.getElementById('box_fg').style.display =
    document.getElementById('box_fg').style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});

// close the box when the user clicks outside of it
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // check if the clicked element is the button or is inside the open box
  var isButton = event.target.closest('#button_fg') !== null;
  var isInsideBox = event.target.closest('#box_fg') !== null;

  // if the clicked element is not the button or inside the box, hide the box
  if (!isButton && !isInsideBox) {
    document.getElementById('box_fg').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
// declare the selectedValue variable
var selectedValue1;
var dropdown_fg = document.getElementById('dropdown_fg');

// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown_fg.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // get the selected option
  var selectedOption1 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

  // save the selected option as a variable
  selectedValue1 = parseInt(selectedOption1);
});


var selectedValue2;
var dropdown_fg2 = document.getElementById('dropdown_fg2');

// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown_fg2.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // get the selected option
  var selectedOption2 = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

  // save the selected option as a variable
  selectedValue2 = parseInt(selectedOption2);
  // check if the selected option is the top option

});
// create a string that points to the directory
var directory = '#';
// add an event listener for the 'change' event on the dropdown menu
dropdown_fg2.addEventListener('change', function() {

  // check if the selectedValue1 and selectedValue2 variables have been assigned values
  if (!isNaN(selectedValue1) && !isNaN(selectedValue2)) {

    // create an array of images
    var images = [];

    // set the starting image
    var startImage = selectedValue1;

    // set the ending image
    var endImage = selectedValue2;

    // set the step size for the images
    var step = 6;

    // create a loop to add the images to the array
    for (var i = startImage; i <= endImage; i += step) {
      var filePath = directory + "gfs_6hr_2m_temp_hour_" + i + '.png';
      // add the image to the array
      images.push(filePath);
    }
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('download-button2');

    // Handle the button click
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      /// Generate gif
      gifshot.createGIF({
        'images': images,
        'gifWidth': 1144,
        'gifHeight': 894,
        'interval': 0.33
      }, function(obj) {
        if (!obj.error) {
          var image = obj.image;

          // Extract the GIF data from the base64-encoded string
          var gifDataString = image.split(',')[1];
          var gifData = new Uint8Array(atob(gifDataString));

          // Create a Blob object that represents the GIF file
          var gifBlob = new Blob([gifData], {
            type: 'image/gif'
          });

          // Use the URL.createObjectURL() method to create a URL for the Blob
          var gifUrl = URL.createObjectURL(gifBlob);

          // You can then use the URL to open the GIF file in a new window or to display it on your website

          animatedImage = document.createElement('img');
          animatedImage.src = gifUrl;
          document.body.appendChild(animatedImage);
          window.open(gifUrl);
        }
      });
    });

  }
})
```

```css
#box_fg {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  /* hide the box by default */
  max-width: 15%;
  /* set a maximum width for the box */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* hide any content that overflows the box */
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 55.3%;
  top: 70.5%;
}

#button_fg {
  position: absolute;
  /* create a positioning context for the list items */
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 55.3%;
  top: 84.8%;
}

#button_fg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #525252;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

#download-button2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 12/13/14 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #button_fg {
    position: absolute;
    /* create a positioning context for the list items */
    width: 23%;
    left: 26vw;
    top: 105vw;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 7vw;
  }
  #box_fg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 26vw;
    top: 78vw;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #button_fg {
    top: 39vw;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  #box_fg {
    top: 32vw;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1050px) {
  #box_fg {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #button_fg {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  #button_fg {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #box_fg {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  #button_fg {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  #box_fg {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="button_fg">Forecast Gif</button>
<div id="box_fg">
  <label>Starting Hour:</label>
  <select id="dropdown_fg">
    <option id="dropdown_fg" value="">Select Hour</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>

  </select>
  <div>
    <label>Ending Hour:</label>
    <select id="dropdown_fg2">
      <option id="dropdown_fg2" value="">Select Hour</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="42">42</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>

    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="download-button2">Download GIF</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is "gifshot"? It is not a defined variable in your code

Comment: it is a function that is used to make gif's I imported it using this <script src="gifshot/dist/gifshot.js"></script>